# Make the "debug" button on the integration test in Flutter open the Chrome browser instead of the Windows app

Tags: flutter

To make the "debug" button on the integration test in Flutter open the Chrome browser instead of the Windows app, what should I change in my test file?

[image]

I attempted to apply the following, but it was unsuccessful:

```
import 'package:flutter_driver/driver_extension.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  enableFlutterDriverExtension(handler: (payload) async {
    if (payload == 'get_platform') {
      return Platform.isAndroid ? 'android' : 'web';
    }
    return null;
  });
  testWidgets('Your test name', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Your test code here
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In vscode status bar there is a "Flutter device" tab (bottom right) that has the current target used when Running/Debugging. If you click on it, you should be able to switch to the desired target.

**Update**

According to [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94245), integration_test does not support web targets yet, so even if you choose Chrome it will throw an error. An alternative using command line is described in the [offical guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction#5b-web)

Comment: Thank you. Can I attach vs code debugger while I am using command line?